# 'sull'orlo del collasso' contro 'all'orlo del collasso'

Tags: word-choice

[Rispondendo ad una domanda su *meta*](https://italian.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125/is-italian-language-still-alive/127#127), ho scritto "sull'orlo del precipizio", che, come noto, è una espressone figurata.

Poi, ho pensato di sostituire "precipizio" con "collasso" e, quindi, scrivere "sull'orlo del collasso", ma nel fare ciò mi sono chiesto se fosse corretto lasciare "sull" o usare "all".

Non so, ma ho l'impressione che "sull'orlo del collasso" non sia quanto di meglio è possibile scrivere perché "sull", a mio giudizio, tende a conferire materialità ad un "orlo" che il *collasso*, a differenza del *precipizio*, effettivamente non ha, mentre "all" no.

Così opinando, "all" sarebbe più corretto di "sull". Confermate? O in questo caso sarebbe possibile modificare solo parzialamente l'espressione iniziale senza che ciò comporti dissonanze?

Comment: No. Non trovo affatto che *all'orlo* sia più corretto in alcun caso.

Comment: @egreg, perche'? L'orlo potrebbe essere la rappresentazione metaforica del limite e, se non erro, 'al limite' e' corretto.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think one should prefer *all'orlo* to *sull'orlo* in any case. They have perhaps slightly different meanings: *sull'orlo del baratro* might suggest you are even looking down the chasm, while *all'orlo* might not bear this additional idea.

Just sensations, perhaps.

What's really bad is the ‘squared metaphor’. In my opinion *all'orlo del collasso* means nothing (and *sull'orlo*, either). *Sembrava sull'orlo del collasso* can better be *Sembrava vicino* (or *prossimo*) *al collasso*. The influence of a well known movie title has made this phrase ubiquitous; but it's ugly nonetheless.

By the way, *sull'orlo del collasso* outscores *all'orlo* by 561000 to 54200 on Google.